# How do I run SMOTE on image data using the packages available?

Tags: cnn, class-imbalance, smote

I need to balance some image datasets, how do I use [SMOTE variants](https://github.com/gykovacs/smote_variants) or the imblearn SMOTE method with images? I can't figure out how to, since they seem to be working only with numerical datasets.

Answer (score 2):

This might be helpful - https://github.com/tgsmith61591/smrt. Synthetic Minority Reconstruction Technique uses a variational auto encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Our image data is generally in the format (8000,128,64,3) this if we pass directly into SMOTE then it'll throw an error as it is designed to input (n_examples, n_feature).

We need to reshape our image to:

```
dataForSmote = x.reshape(8000, 128 * 64 * 3)
```

Then,

```
smote = SMOTE(sampling_strategy = 0.8)

x_smote, y_smote = smote.fit_resample(dataForSmote , y)

X_smote = x_smote.reshape(10800, 128, 64, 3)
```

Here, I assumed 6K as majority set and 2K as minority set, if we calculate 80% of of 6K we get 4.8K i.e. 2.8K new synthetic examples added total becomes 8+2.8 = 10.8K

Use `X_smote` and `y_smote` for training.